# bisect everything, from initial commit

Tags: git, git-bisect

Say I have a small project with a very fast test script, and I just want to bisect everything, from the initial commit to the curret commit. How can I do that?

To clarify, I don't want to waste time identifying a commit that is good and a commit that is bad, so I'm looking for a quick way to mark the latest commit as bad, and the initial commit as good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git bisect start
git bisect good
git bisect bad `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`
git bisect run ./test.sh
```

Or incorporate these commands into an alias, e.g.:

```
bisect-all = !git bisect start && git bisect bad &&\
        git bisect good `git rev-list --max-parents=0 --first-parent HEAD`
```

And then just use `git bisect-all`, `git bisect run ./test.sh`.

Creating an alias to handle the whole process is slightly more complicated:

```
quick-bisect = !sh -c 'git bisect start && git bisect bad &&\
        git bisect good `git rev-list --max-parents=0 --first-parent HEAD` &&\
        git bisect run "$@" && git bisect reset' -
```

But with that, you can simply run `git quick-bisect ./test.sh`.

---

If you're using a version of git older than 1.7.4.2, you won't have the `--max-parents` option, so will need to use something like `git rev-list HEAD | tail -n 1` instead.

Comment: maybe add `--first-parent` to the rev-list to avoid multiple-root trouble when e.g. projects get merged, and quote the params, "$@", to avoid unwanted word splitting?

Comment: @jthill: Thanks, I added `--first-parent`. It took me a while to figure out what you meant about unwanted word splitting, but even with quotes `"$@"`, words are split: `git quick-bisect ./test.sh "ONE TWO THREE"` runs `./test.sh ONE TWO THREE`. What's going on?

Comment: If its in an alias I think you might need to escape the quotes, not sure otherwise.